# How can I access the C# performance counter in the code?

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter, counter

I want to use the performance counter output in my program. How can I access the performance counter in code without using the perfmon.exe. I want to create my own performance counter app.

Comment: Try this reference [An Introduction To Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8590/An-Introduction-To-Performance-Counters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is exposed via the [PerformanceCounter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter).

Comment: I want to see the performance of a WCF service using the Performancecounter class without using the perfmon tool. I want to know the #of operations performed by the service. Anyone there can give me a sample?

Comment: Looks like the most useful links in that KB page you linked to are dead.  Too bad, it looked like a nice landing page for learning about this stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You can fully interact with performancecounters throught the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` classes ([Documentation and examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx)).