# Accessing WCF Performance Counter Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, performancecounter

So I've seen a lot of posts about using PerfMon and such to view WCF Performance counters after they are enabled.

I am researching how I could access the Endpoint, service, and operation performance counters programmatically every so often and print it out in my own custom file.

So first of all, I need to place the following in my Wcf's config file to enable performance counters

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

So for example, if I want to just know the general call duration from the endpoint performance counters, I was thinking of grabbing all instances of the Call Durations performance counters and obtaining an average of that duration value.

I was thinking of doing the following:
Use:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()
```

and find the Category I am looking for.  So I would look for the ServiceModelEndpoint category. Then I would use

```
GetCounters("Calls Duration")
```

to retrieve all instances of the counter so I can loop through and get the average call duration value.

Please keep in mind this is my first foray into performance counters and what I mentioned above is sort of the pseudocode I had in mind to retrieve the value I'm looking for.  To the people who are more knowledgeable in this area, would the algorithm above be a valid/good way to access the counters that I need and do you foresee any complications that would deter me from getting the pseudocode to work? If you have suggestions on other ways I can achieve what I'm looking for, feel free to let me know :D

Thanks for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access the C# performance counter in the code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712649/how-can-i-access-the-c-sharp-performance-counter-in-the-code)

Comment: Maybe I missed something but most of the links points to how to add custom counters or view counters in perfmon which I don't want to do?  The class api is what I used originally to write up post and is my interpretation of how to utilize the api of accessing the wcf performance counter. I was looking for someone to verify or suggest maybe a more efficient way of accessing them?

Comment: Your approach sounds fine to me. I've not personally attempted to read performance counters from code - we use perfmon for that - but I frequently write code to create new counters and update them. For reading, if you follow through the links to that other question you'll eventually get to [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516(v=vs.71).aspx) which shows how to do more or less what perfmon does.