# How to make the speech tell Disk Reads and Writes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

i have a program setup that in startup it tells the user the total uptime of there computer. i also want it to tell their current disk read speed and their current disk write speed. i cant seem to figure it out. i have the performance counters set up for both i just need to know how to write the code to pull the information and insert it into the speech message.

i have these 2 lines to pull the info from performance counter. i need to know how to send it to the diskWriteSpeedmessage

```
PerformanceCounter perfDiskRead = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Read Time", "_Total");

perfDiskRead.NextValue();

PerformanceCounter perfDiskWrite = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Write Time", "_Total");

perfDiskWrite.NextValue();
```

If your wondering what my speech message code is it is

```
string diskWriteSpeadmessage = string.Format("your current disk write spead is {0} megabytes per second");

Speak(diskWriteSpeadmessage, VoiceGender.Male);
```

Comment: Your question is about how to read the performance counter? If so, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2712649).

Comment: its not reading the performance counter. its getting the information sent to the speech command @KenWhite

Comment: Then I don't see a question. If you have the performance counter information, and you have the `string.Format` portion, you just need to provide the performance counter information as the `{0}` to `string.Format`. What **exactly** are you asking for help with? How to use `string.Format`? Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you want help with here, because as it is now I can't tell (and apparently neither can anyone else, as you have no answer).

Comment: @KenWhite i have edited it a little see if that helps

Comment: @Kaedan Caine: Is the problem that `diskWriteSpeadmessage`[SIC] has the wrong value, or does that part work but `Speak` does not?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it speaks the line that i wrote it to speak but it dosnt speak it with the info i need it to. it just uses 0 instead of the actual read write speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the format item `{0}` with actual disk speed, you need to pass it as a second parameter to `string.Format`:

```
string diskWriteSpeadmessage = 
  string.Format("your current disk write speed is {0} megabytes per second",
    perfDiskWrite.NextValue());
```