# Two throttling for one WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, throttling

I am developing a system under WCF services which contain two modules and this service is self hosted. One of the module has to handle multiple clients whereas another module has to handle one request at a time for direct file download. Other request on this module is set on a queue.
[image]

System should hold other request if it for module two but it should handle requests for module

1. How can I use WCF service Throttling to achieve this? I tried implementing two throttling but it did not work.
2. Is it possible to count number of pending request in WCF throttling?

I am trying to get this done by using MySQL to hold up the queue but I am not able to hold current request that is for module 2. Is it possible to hold user request and process it after current process is completed?

Comment: I think no. One throttling config per service

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way to obtain the two throttling under one host is to separate the interface service and define individual endpoints. This allowed me to use two throttling under one host but under two different ports (*which is no problem ;)*).

About counting the number of pending request, I think I need to implement the performance counter by taking some support from these links:

- [How can I access the C# performance counter in the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712649/how-can-i-access-the-c-sharp-performance-counter-in-the-code)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316365?wa=wsignin1.0

I will update if I am able to implement pending request count in WCF service.